# Is it possible to get a hold of values associated with an enum from inside an annotation processor?

Tags: java, enums, annotations, annotation-processing

In the case below, I want to get the value of `MyString.class` since the `@RendererType` is of value `TEXT` on the field inside the annotation processor's execution.

This is my custom annotation:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Renderer {

  RendererType value() default RendererType.TEXT;
}
```

which contains a `RendererType` enum whos definition is:

```java
public enum RendererType {
  TEXT(new Class[] {MyString.class}),
  TEXTAREA(new Class[] {MyString.class}),
  CHECKBOX(new Class[] {MyBoolean.class});

  private final Class<?>[] supportedTypes;

  RendererType(Class<?>[] classes) {
    this.supportedTypes = classes;
  }

  public Class<?>[] getSupportedTypes() {
    return this.supportedTypes;
  }
}
```

Example usage of `@Renderer` on a field in a POJO would look like:

```java
@Renderer(RendererType.CHECKBOX)
boolean old = true;
```

This is the annotation processor `StringProcessor`, for `@Renderer` annotation:

```java
import com.company.annotation.metadata.Renderer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.Messager;
import javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

public class StringProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

  private Messager messager;

  @Override
  public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
    super.init(processingEnv);
    messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean process(
      final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, final RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

    for (TypeElement typeElement : annotations) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(typeElement)) {

            TypeMirror typeMirror = element.asType();

            ElementKind elementKind = element.getKind();

            if (elementKind.equals(ElementKind.FIELD)) {
                System.out.println("FIELD");
                // Do something to get `supportedTypes` associated with the enum value
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
    final Set<String> annotations = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Renderer.class.getName()));
    return annotations;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Slaw `getSupportedTypes` is not part of `Renderer` class though

Comment: Forgot the call to `value()`. I added an answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your annotation processor has access to `Renderer` at compile-time, which I assume it does given your implementation of `getSupportedAnnotationTypes`, then the easiest approach is to use a class literal with [`AnnotatedConstruct#getAnnotation(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/AnnotatedConstruct.html). That will give you an instance of `Renderer` which you can then use like normal.

### Example

###### Renderer.java

```java
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Renderer {

  RendererType value() default RendererType.TEXT;
}
```

###### RendererType.java

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

public enum RendererType {
  TEXT(String.class),
  TEXTAREA(String.class),
  CHECKBOX(Boolean.class, boolean.class);

  // using unmodifiable list because lists are generally better than
  // arrays and you no longer have to worry about returning a defensive
  // copy to avoid globally-scoped modifications
  private final List<Class<?>> supportedTypes;

  // vararg parameter makes declaring the constants a little cleaner
  RendererType(Class<?>... supportedTypes) {
    // List::of returns an unmodifiable list
    this.supportedTypes = List.of(supportedTypes);
  }

  public List<Class<?>> getSupportedTypes() {
    return supportedTypes;
  }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** If you still want to use `Class<?>[]` then make sure that `getSupportedTypes()` returns a *copy* of the array.</sup>

###### RendererProcessor.java

```java
package com.example.processing;

import com.example.Renderer;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;

// replace source version as needed
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_21)
// or override 'getSupportedAnnotationTypes'
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.example.Renderer")
public class RendererProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

  @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Renderer.class)) {
      // no need to verify element is field due to @Target meta-annotation
      Renderer renderer = element.getAnnotation(Renderer.class);
      List<Class<?>> supportedTypes = renderer.value().getSupportedTypes();
      // TODO: do something with 'supportedTypes'
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** If you override `getSupportedAnnotationTypes` then `return Set.of(Renderer.class.getName())` can be the implementation.</sup>